# Why am I losing information?

Tags: c#, math, double

I was coding when I found it:

```
double v = 555.55;
int v2 = (int)Math.Floor(v / 100.0);
double v3 = v2 * 100;
double v4 = v - v2 * 100;
double v5 = v - v3;
```

At the end, the code says:

```
v = 555.55
v2 = 5 
v3 = 500 
v4 = 55.549999999999955 
v5 = 55.549999999999955
```

So, why is that happening and how could I fix it?

Comment: What is the expected result? The code is doing exactly what you told it to do.

Comment: What do you mean "the code says"? How come in some of your printout there are only 2 decimal digits, and in others there are more than 10 decimal digits? How exactly are you printing each one of these variables? I bet that if you print `v` in the same precision that you're printing `v4` and `v5`, you'll see the exact same value.

Comment: Pretty sure this is duplicate  of “floating point math is broken”... but need to wait for clarification from OP

Comment: 555.55 - (5 * 100) = 55.55 is different from 55.549999999999955. I wanna know why am I losing 4,5 * 10^(-14) in the process.

Comment: @goodvibration I saw those values from VS2019, but if I print them the console displays the same.

Comment: Thank you, @AlexeiLevenkov I'm going to see that question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, *fractional part* of `double v = 555.55` (which is `double v = 0.55`) is a *periodic* binary fraction which
*can't be represented exactly*. What options do we have? Let's make a smallest possible change of `555.55`
(i.e. we change the last bit of `555.55`):

```
  double v = 555.55;
  int v2 = (int)Math.Floor(v / 100.0); 
  double v4 = v - v2 * 100;

  // Here we increment the last bit of v (minimum possible change) 
  byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(v);

  bytes[0] = (byte) (bytes[0] + 1);

  double d = BitConverter.ToDouble(bytes);
  double dv = d - v2 * 100;

  string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    $" v  = {v:R}",
    $"v4  = {v4:R}",
    $" v' = {d:R}",
    $"v4' = {dv:R}");

 Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 v  = 555.55
v4  = 55.549999999999955
 v' = 555.5500000000001
v4' = 55.55000000000007
```

So the only options we have either `55.549999999999955` or `55.55000000000007`; please, note, that `55.549999999999955` is a better one (`4.5e-14` < `7.0e-14`).

How to *fix* it? As you can see, *floating point* arithmetics brings *rounding error*; often we can change `double` into `decimal` which is standard practice if `555.55` is some kind of *currency* value (say, dollars and cents):

```
  decimal v = 555.55m;
  int v2 = (int)Math.Floor(v / 100m);
  decimal v3 = v2 * 100;
  decimal v4 = v - v2 * 100;
  decimal v5 = v - v3;

  string result = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    $" v = {v}",
    $"v2 = {v2}",
    $"v3 = {v3}",
    $"v4 = {v4}",
    $"v5 = {v5}");

  Console.Write(result);
```

**Outcome:**

```
 v = 555.55
v2 = 5
v3 = 500
v4 = 55.55
v5 = 55.55
```

Answer (score -1):

Well, by turning a double into an int, you are going to lose information, because an int is a whole number, so everything after the decimal point gets cut away.

Comment: That does not explain the output specified in the question (i.e., the diff between `v` and `v4` or `v5`).